# Warning message for a primary key constraint

Tags: sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a problem with assigning a primary key in one of the tables containing employee info. There is no unique column in that table, The only option I am left with is taking combination of three columns as a primary key.

1. But it gives a warning message as `Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'pk_hrempid' has maximum length of 1530 bytes.For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail` I came to know that this would be a major problem in the future for inserting the data. Is there a solution for this warning?
2. **Other question is can I put an auto-increment value as a unique id, is it recommended?** I want to make sure that it does not give problems in the future as I have many tables containing employee info from the other departments. Some employees may be present in two or more tables

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would be interested to know the column datatype definitions that gave rise to that error.

Comment: It's hard to debug SQL DDL code we cannot see ;) Don't be shy, post the attribute names data types and sample data. You may find someone here with domain knowledge of your area of business who can point you in the direction of an industry standard key or other trusted source for identifiers.

Comment: @Widor..Thanks for the clue..All my data-types had a default nvarchar(255)(as I have up-sized from access)which is too long for the data in the columns, I have changed the data-types for the primary key columns, then there is no warning for the primary key! Do I have to change the data-types for all the other columns(which also have small data when compared to the nvarchar)...or is it okay to put as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst is it sounds from your attempt at a compound primary key that you're attempting the best-practice of using a "natural key", there's nothing 'wrong' with using an auto-incrementing `ID` field.

If your suggested fields are too large to be used as a key, perhaps they weren't the best choice in the first place. Could you add another "natural" key column with a better datatype perhaps?

Don't forget to take into account the optimizations that are possible by choosing good indexes and suitable datatypes for tables that are going to be heavily-queried.

Comment: I guess you meant to say, "There's nothing 'wrong' with using a surrogate key _in addition to_ a natural key...." (aside: I would disagree) but the problem here is the DBMS cannot enforce the natural key.

Comment: @OTTA I should qualify that with "if the natural key is feasible" or "if the natural key lends itself to being a primary key." That is, if both the 'natural' and 'surrogate' are small, numeric, and indexable then go with the 'natural' one every time.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestion. If I put an auto increment value as the primary key for all the employees in all the tables, I think it would lead to confusion..doesn't it?

Comment: @user939615 Yes, you only put an auto increment `ID` on the `Employee` table. Any table that also refers to that `ID` will just be of the same datatype, but _not_ auto-incrementing - and may have a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship to the `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a limitation of a primary key. You can not have a PK larger that 900 bytes.
2. You could add a identity column to the table and set it as the primary key. I prefer to use Guids as they are globally unique.

Comment: 1. Surely this is a limitation of SQL Server? 2. this would not prevent duplicates in existing three columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with an auto-increment type solution for the primary key, problem with using personal data for this sort of thing is that you cannot guarantee uniqueness which is the fundamental requirement of a primary key.